# Disable Samsung Hacks on Standard Android Styles and Themes

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, samsung-mobile

Samsung seems to be overriding default android styles and themes (they've been doing this for years). Doing simple things like putting a SeekBar in your layout:

```
<SeekBar
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

works fine on every other device, except Samsung. On a Samsung device the SeekBar thumb is not centered vertically, it's moved up above the SeekBar's center line.

The SeekBar isn't the only example of standard UI not working correctly on Samsung devices. It's a general problem across many of the standard components.

How can I disable Samsung's hacks on the Android standard styles / themes in my app?

Comment: Generally, it helps to explicitly set the Theme in your manifest. If you leave it default, Samsung will strike and break your app. A couple of versions ago, TabHost was consistently broken on Samsung devices.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am doing that. I'm using `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` as the parent. There must be a deeper level of evil at work here.

Comment: Which Samsung devices are you seeing this `SeekBar` behavior on? I'd be curious to try to reproduce the results using non-`appcompat-v7` themes.

Comment: For example, [this old sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WidgetCatalog/SeekBar) does not specify a theme. On a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N900, running Android 5.0, the `SeekBar` does not exhibit the behavior that you describe. If I update it to use `Theme.Material` explicitly, I get the same UI as without a theme (as expected), and again without exhibiting the problem that you describe.

Comment: Weird, for me, the thumb is centered vertically only if I have `wrap_content` on my layout_height.